# Not applying CSS class?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Seems my CSS class defined in the head of the document isn't being recognized or applied.  Any idea what I'm missing, or doing wrong?

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ewajhm49/)

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <title>EXAMPLE</title>
      <style>
          .show_x
          {
              visibility: visible;
          }
          //
          .hide_x
          {
              visibility: hidden;
          }
      </style>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
        <span class="hide_x glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign text-danger"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign text-danger" style="visibility: hidden;"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would expect to see neither warning sign, but I see the first one.  The second one is properly hidden.

Comment: you have two closing </head> tags, I'd start with addressing that first and see if it helps. I'm assuming there is a single </html> closing tag that isn't shown in your sample.

Comment: Why is there a "//". When I remove it in the debugger, the css works as expected.

Comment: And that was it.  Silly type-o.  Thanks

Comment: check this updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ewajhm49/11/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inline comments do not work in CSS, so where you have

```
      .show_x
      {
          visibility: visible;
      }
      // <-- invalid CSS
      .hide_x
      {
          visibility: hidden;
      }
```

Which probably makes the browser stop processing that CSS block, conveniently right before the more visible of the two (or less visible) ... anyway the one that's easier to see when it's applied as it hides stuff ... you get what I mean.

In CSS we can use only block comments `/**/`, it's a simple mistake.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <title>EXAMPLE</title>
      <style>
          .show_x
          {
              visibility: visible;
          }
        
          .hide_x
          {
              visibility: hidden;
          }
      </style>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
        <span class="hide_x glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign text-danger"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign text-danger" style="visibility: hidden;"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```